# Preprocess getter

Tags: webforms

I have a getter parameter of type "User Id" that should define the emails the form is sent to.

The internal hidden field "email" should be preprocessed before the form is build. So that the webform is not submittable if the validation of the get parameter does fail (user id does not exist).

Where can I validate that paramater before the hidden field is set?